# Can't keep WinKey+Up from moving my form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-7

I am trying to set a window at the bottom right of my screen. Its FormBorderStyle is set to None. I don't want the user to have the ability to move it around. Unfortunately, if the user presses Winkey+Up (maximize in Win7), it will relocate the form to (0,0) on my desktop.

I tried resetting the location in the LocationChanged event but when I changed the Left/Top or Location properties, they would not actually change.

Does anybody have any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: You'll probably need to change the forms `WindowState` back to normal if you expect to be able to move it around.

Comment: This solved the issue, actually. If you could post it as an answer I can mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't programmatically change your form's location if it is maximized. You'll need to change its [`WindowState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate.aspx) property to [`FormWindowState.Normal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.formwindowstate.aspx) before trying to set its location.

Answer (score 0):

You need a GlobalSystemHook, and itsn't a trivial work.
At [this url (CodeProject)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6362/Global-System-Hooks-in-NET) there is an useful example.

Comment: Fortunately for me, M. Babcock's worked for me. Thanks for your input, though.

Answer (score 0):

Set your `FormBorderStyle` to one of `FixedSingle`, `Fixed3D`, `FixedDialog` or `FixedToolWindow` **AND** set `MaximizeBox` and `MinimizeBox` to false.

Comment: I need the form border to not be there for aesthetic reasons. M.Babcock resolved my issue, though. Thanks for the input!